# Why don't I get a warning when I redeclare the Perl foreach control variable?

Tags: perl, variables, warnings

Why is there no warning thrown for the redeclaration of `$i` in the following code?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

for my $i (1..3) {
  my $i = 'DUMMY';
  print Dumper $i;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Actually, you only get warnings for redefinitions in the same scope. Writing:

```
use warnings;
my $i;
{
  my $i;
  # do something to the inner $i
}
# do something to the outer $i
```

is perfectly valid.
I am not sure if the Perl internals handle it this way, but you can think of your `for` loop as being parsed as

```
{
  my $i;
  for $i ( ... ) { ... }
  # the outer scope-block parens are important!
};
```

Comment: Your second example is not at all the same as the first, because of the different scope, as well as the loop iterator being aliased to the array elements (meaning if you change $i within the loop, you will change your array, or generate a warning if the elements are constants).

Comment: they are both within the same scope of the for block whereas your examples are both in different scopes.

Comment: The aliasing in the second example works as expected, try it out yourself:

my @a = ( 1 .. 3 );
{ my $i; for $i ( 1 .. 3 ) { $i = 'x'; } }
print "a: @a";

As for being in the same scope: as the question shows, the declaration
in the for expression is clearly not in the same scope as the declaration
in the inner block.

Comment: when a `for` loop uses a previously declared lexical as its loop variable, the effect is the same as if the loop variable was declared with `my` in the `for` declaration

Comment: Oh my, I guess, it's been 5 years since I had last looked into perlsyn ... Quote: if variables are declared with my in the initialization section of the for, the lexical scope of those variables is exactly the for loop (the body of the loop and the control sections). I.E. there IS an implicit scope block around the whole control-structure, and my second example is really spot on. Cheers

Comment: wouldn't your second example make $i visible outside the for block? from perlsyn "If the variable is preceded with the keyword "my", then it is lexically scoped, and is therefore visible only within the loop." your example doesn't quite match what i'm ask, or am i missing something?

nevermind, didn't read the other responses.

Answer (score 2):

You would get a warning if you redeclare a `my`, `our` or `state` variable in the current scope or statement. The first `$i` isn't actually a lexical variable. You can prove this using `Devel::Peek`:

```
use Devel::Peek;   

for my $i (1) {
    Dump $i;
}  

SV = IV(0x81178c8) at 0x8100bf8
REFCNT = 2
FLAGS = (IOK,READONLY,pIOK)
IV = 1
```

There's no `PADMY` flag in FLAGS, which would indicate that `$i` is a lexical variable, declared with `my`.