# Why does perl not warn when redeclaring a variable in an inner scope?

Tags: perl

As a bit of a perl novice, I just ran into a bug where I accidentally did something like (example simplified):

```
my $i=0;
 for(my $i=0;$i<10; $i++)
  {
    print $i;
  }
print $i; # $i is zero, my code expected 9
```

From [Why don't I get a warning when I redeclare the Perl foreach control variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273784/why-dont-i-get-a-warning-when-i-redeclare-the-perl-foreach-control-variable) I understand that this behavior is expected; I should not get a warning unless the re-declaration is in the same scope.

However, I can not understand why this is the case. Why would perl not issue a warning here? It seems to me that it would be a likely cause of errors, and usually not intended. Is there some common case where this is normal programming style, so that the warning would be annoying?

Comment: @Mat - more likely than not, such code is a result of an error during manual refactoring as opposed to by design. E.g. more likely a bug than expected thing.

Comment: Duh. And because people sometimes do stuff that they didn't intend to do, compilers have warnings.

Comment: @Mat: `my $foo; my $foo;` also explicitly requests a new variable with `my`, but Perl still issues the warning _"my" variable $foo masks earlier declaration in same scope_. It's not just a matter of "you're making an explicit request".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perl doesn't tend to warn for style issues, but I find it hard to believe that someone would intentionally want to have the same var name at different scope depths.

The only case where it might be useful that comes to mind is

```
{
    my $x = $x;
    ... do some something that changes $x ...
}
# $x is restored here.
```

On the plus side, there is a [`perlcritic`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlcritic) [rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl%3a%3aCritic%3a%3aPolicy%3a%3aVariables%3a%3aProhibitReusedNames) to identify such a problem.

Comment: @dolmen, Not sure I'd call it a recommendation. It's an option.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, even though it doesn't really answer my question. Perlcritic seems like a useful tool to help with issues like this.

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't answer your question??? It might not the be only or correct answers, but I gave you two!! (Perl doesn't warn for style issues, and it can actually be useful.)

Comment: It was not intended as criticism. I had hoped for a (in my view) more satisfactory answer, but I accept that there may not be such an answer. I don't really consider this a style issue, but I guess that is a matter of taste. The situation which you suggest as useful strikes me as confusing and risky, but again, I realize others may see it differently.

Comment: You asked "why" - this answer is canonically why.  If your request was "convince me that warning is a good idea," then you'd have a point because you're still unconvinced.  But the question was "why".