# What's the difference between 'for' and 'foreach' in Perl?

Tags: perl, loops, syntax, for-loop, foreach

I see these used interchangeably. What's the difference?

Comment: They used to be separate ideas, but now they are synonyms. Perl figures out what to do based on what's in the ( ) instead of using the keyword. Blame the people who couldn't type an extra four characters. :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is no difference. From [perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops):

> The `foreach` keyword is actually a synonym for the `for` keyword, so you can use `foreach` for readability or `for` for brevity.

Answer (score 15):

> I see these used interchangeably.

There is no difference other than that of syntax.

Comment: +1 Yes, Perl is quite rich in syntactic sugar. There Is More Then One Way to Say It.

Answer (score 6):

Four letters.

They're <strike>functionally</strike> identical, just spelled differently.

Comment: Actually the compile down to the same opcodes. So for all intents and purposes, they are identical.

Answer (score 6):

Ever since its [introduction in perl-2.0](http://github.com/github/perl/blob/perl-2.0/perl.man.1), `foreach` has been synonymous with `for`. It's a nod to the C shell's [`foreach`](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Builtin_commands.html#foreach) command.

In my own code, in the rare case that I'm using a C-style for-loop, I write

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i)
```

but for iterating over an array, I spell out

```
foreach my $x (@a)
```

I find that it reads better in my head that way.

Comment: I find the opposite: I always use `for my $x (@a)`. I prefer Python's `for x in a` loops, or maybe even PHP's `for(@a as $x)`. I never use C-style `for` loops. I'd write what you have as `for my $i (0 .. $n)`. Perl special-case optimizes that not to create an unnecessary list, so the difference between it and your explicit C-style `for` loop should be negligible, and I think it's more readable that way.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: So you never have the need to do something more complex than a 1 by 1? I can think of several different applications where the C style loop is simply the best way to write it. The simplest case I can think right now is wanting to go for odds or evens only with something like `for (my $i = 1; $i < @x; $i += 2) {...}`

Answer (score 2):

From http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops

> The foreach keyword is actually a synonym for the for keyword, so you
>   can use either. If VAR is omitted, $_ is set to each value.

```
# Perl's C-style
for (;;) {
    # do something
}

for my $j (@array) {
    print $j;
}

foreach my $j (@array) {
    print $j;
}
```

However:

> If any part of LIST is an array, foreach will get very confused if you
>   add or remove elements within the loop body, for example with splice.
>   So don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

> The foreach keyword is actually a synonym for the for keyword, so you can use foreach for readability or for for brevity. (Or because the Bourne shell is more familiar to you than csh, so writing for comes more naturally.) If VAR is omitted, $_ is set to each value.

Answer (score -1):

There is a subtle difference (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) :

> The foreach loop iterates over a normal list value and sets the variable VAR to be each element of the list in turn. If the variable is preceded with the keyword my, then it is lexically scoped, and is therefore visible only within the loop. Otherwise, the variable is implicitly local to the loop and regains its former value upon exiting the loop. If the variable was previously declared with my, it uses that variable instead of the global one, but it's still localized to the loop. This implicit localization occurs only in a foreach loop.

This program :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $var = 1;
for ($var=10;$var<=10;$var++) {
  print $var."\n"; # print 10
  foo(); # print 10
}

print $var."\n"; # print 11    

foreach $var(100) {
  print $var."\n"; # print 100
  foo(); # print 11 !
}

sub foo {
  print $var."\n";
}
```

will produce that :

```
10
10
11
100
11
```

Comment: That is explained also http://stackoverflow.com/q/5398520/579750 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2238576/579750 .

Comment: This is actually a wrong answer, since this happens in both `for` and `foreach` loop. You can try it yourself - if you flip `for` and `foreach` in the code, nothing happens

Comment: You're wrong, the result is the same : foreach call to foo() prints the value of the global $var (hence 1), since the "for" call to foo() prints the value of the local $var (hence 10)

Comment: Maybe we don't understand each other. What I am saying is there is no difference between `for` and `foreach`, since if you flip `foreach` and `for` (in your own code) you have the same results as before; so, there is no difference between `for` and `foreach`.

Comment: After flipping : 100 1 1 10 10

Comment: Not what I get. I get 10 10 11 100 11 after and before flipping. Using perl 5.10.1 on linux x86_64.

Comment: This answer is 50% accurate: there is a difference in the scope of `for` and `foreach` but the example is wrong.

Comment: @pera The answer and the example are both wrong. Any difference in the scope or anything else is set by whatever you put inside the parentheses, not by the keyword itself.

Answer (score -2):

In case of the "for" you can use the three steps.

1) Initialization 
  2) Condition Checking 
  3) Increment or decrement

But in case of "foreach" you are not able increment or decrement the value. It always take the increment value as 1.

Comment: This is not true. You can use both syntax conventions with both keywords (for and foreach) with no difference on anything other than the keyword itself.

Comment: It will loop for 5 times printing 12345, we havent used steps mentioned by you. `print $_ for (1..5)`