# PERL Scope in foreach loops

Tags: perl

I have a perl scope question.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

our @cycles = (0,1,2,3,4);

foreach my $cycle (@cycles){
    my $nextcycle = 0;
    foreach $nextcycle (@cycles){
        if ($cycle+1 == $nextcycle){
            print "found cycle+1, $nextcycle\n";
            last;
        }
    }
    print "current=$cycle, nextcycle=$nextcycle\n";
}
```

The output I get:

> found cycle+1, 1
>
> current=0, nextcycle=0
>
> found cycle+1, 2
>
> current=1, nextcycle=0
>
> found cycle+1, 3
>
> current=2, nextcycle=0
>
> found cycle+1, 4
>
> current=3, nextcycle=0
>
> current=4, nextcycle=0

I expected this:

> found cycle+1, 1
>
> current=0, nextcycle=1
>
> found cycle+1, 2
>
> current=1, nextcycle=2
>
> found cycle+1, 3
>
> current=2, nextcycle=3
>
> found cycle+1, 4
>
> current=3, nextcycle=4
>
> current=4, nextcycle=0

I further modified the loop to look like this and got what I wanted:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

our @cycles = (0,1,2,3,4);

foreach my $cycle (@cycles){
    my $nextcycle = 0;
    foreach my $tempcycle (@cycles){
        if ($cycle+1 == $tempcycle){
            $nextcycle = $tempcycle;
            print "found cycle+1, $nextcycle\n";
            last;
        }
    }
    print "current=$cycle, nextcycle=$nextcycle\n";
}
```

I want to know why the first loop didn't work!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the default scope of foreach loop in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238576/what-is-the-default-scope-of-foreach-loop-in-perl)

Answer (score 9):

From the [Perl manual on the `foreach` construct](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops):

> The foreach loop iterates over a
>   normal list value and sets the
>   variable VAR to be each element of the
>   list in turn. If the variable is
>   preceded with the keyword my, then it
>   is lexically scoped, and is therefore
>   visible only within the loop.
>   Otherwise, the variable is implicitly
>   local to the loop and regains its
>   former value upon exiting the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The scope of the variable in `foreach my ...` is the `foreach` loop itself.  From `perldoc perlsyn`:

> There is one minor difference: if variables are declared with `my` in
>   the initialization section of the `for`, the lexical scope of those
>   variables is exactly the `for` loop (the body of the loop and the
>   control sections).