# Parsing Apache logs in Perl

Tags: string, perl, apache, parsing, logging

**UPDATED 5-10-2013**

Okay, so now I can filter out the IP addresses with no problem. Now come the next three things I'd like to do which I thought could easily be done with `sort($keys)`, but I was wrong and then trying a slightly more complex approach below didn't seem to be the solution either. The next thing I need to accomplish is gathering dates, and browser version. I will provide a sample of the formatting of my log files and my current code.

**APACHE LOG**

```
24.235.131.196 - - [10/Mar/2004:00:57:48 -0500] "GET http://www.google.com/iframe.php HTTP/1.0" 500 414 "http://www.google.com/iframe.php" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows 98)"
```

**My Code**

```
#!usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my %seen = ();
open(FILE, "< access_log") or die "unable to open file  $!";    

while( my $line = <FILE>) {
    chomp $line;

    # regex for ip address.
    if( $line =~ /(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/ ) {  
        $seen{$1}++;
    }

    #regex for date an example is [09\Mar\2009:05:30:23]
    if( $line =~ /\[[\d]{2}\\.*[\d]{4}\:[\d]{2}\:[\d]{2}\]*/) {
        print "\n\n $line matched : $_\n";
    }

}
close FILE;
my $i = 0;

# program bugs out if I uncomment the below line, 
# but to my understanding this is essentially what I'm trying to do.
# for my $key ( keys %seen ) (keys %date) {
for my $key ( keys %seen ) {
    my ($ip) = sort {$a cmp $b}($key); 
    # also I'd like to be able to sort the IP addresses and if 
    # I do it the proper numeric way it generates errors saying contents are not numeric. 
    print @$ip->[$i] . "\n";
    # print "The IPv4 address is : $key and has accessed the server $seen{$key} times. \n";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're pretty close. And yes, I would use a `hash`. It's commonly called a "seen hash".

```
#!usr/bin/perl 

use warnings;
use strict;

my $log = "web.log";
my %seen = ();

open (my $fh, "<", $log) or die "unable to open $log: $!"; 

while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;

    if( $line =~ /(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/ ){
        $seen{$1}++;
    }
}
close $fh;

for my $key ( keys %seen ) {
    print "$key: $seen{$key}\n";
}
```

Here's a sample log file with some output:

```
$ cat web.log 
[Mon Sep 21 02:35:24 1999] some msg blah blah
[Mon Sep 21 02:35:24 1999] 192.1.1.1
[Mon Sep 21 02:35:24 1999] 1.1.1.1
[Mon Sep 21 02:35:24 1999] 10.1.1.9
[Mon Sep 21 02:35:24 1999] 192.1.1.1
[Mon Sep 21 02:35:24 1999] 10.1.1.5
[Mon Sep 21 02:35:24 1999] 10.1.1.9
[Mon Sep 21 02:35:24 1999] 192.1.1.1
$ test.pl
1.1.1.1: 1
192.1.1.1: 3
10.1.1.9: 2
10.1.1.5: 1
```

*A few things I would be careful of:*

`my @array = <FH>;` this will pull the entire file into memory, which isn't a great idea. Especially in this case for log files, they can grow pretty large. Even more so if not `rotated` properly. `for` or `foreach` will have this same problem. `while` being best practice for reading from a file.

You should be in the habit of using the 3-arg lexically scoped `open` as in my example above.

Your `die` statement shouldn't be so "precise". See my message for `die`. Since the reason could be permissions, doesn't exist, locked, etc...

**UPDATE**

This will work for your dates.

```
my $line = '[09\Mar\2009:05:30:23]: plus some message';

#example is [09\Mar\2009:05:30:23]
if( $line =~ /(\[[\d]{2}\\.*\\[\d]{4}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}\])/ ){
   print "$line matched: $1\n"; 
}
```

**UPDATE2**

There's a few things you've done wrong.

I don't see you storing stuff into a date `hash`.

```
print "\n\n $line matched : $_\n";
```

Should look like your `seen hash`, which doesn't make too much sense. What are you trying to do with this stored date data?

```
$data{$1} = "some value, which is up to you";
```

You cannot loop over two `hashes` in one `for` loop.

```
for my $foo (keys %h)(keys %h2) { # do stuff }
```

And for the last sorting bit, you should just `sort` the `keys`

```
for my $key (sort keys %seen ) {
```

Comment: @JohnnyDiamond08 There is no [difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279471/whats-the-difference-between-for-and-foreach-in-perl).

Comment: So now I'm trying to do something similar with dates I'm attempting to pull from a log file and I guess there's a few issues I keep running into. I've changed my initial post and commented where I'm having troubles.

Comment: I re-updated what I have. Thank you so much for all your help so far. Any ideas for these last few questions.

Comment: @JohnnyDiamond08 I think I covered all your new questions.