# Perl foreach loop variable scope

Tags: perl, foreach, scope

I am new to perl and was confused with perl scoping rules after I wrote below code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $i = 0;
foreach $i(5..10){
    print $i."\n";
}
print "Outside loop i = $i\n";
```

I expected output to be like :

```
5
6
7
8
9
10
Outside loop i = 10
```

But its giving :

```
5
6
7
8
9
10
Outside loop i = 0
```

So the variable $i value is not changing after the loop exits. Whats going on in here?

Comment: Side note, unrelated to your problem. Since you mentioned that you're new to Perl and just in case you haven't already been hit over the head a thousand times about this: you should *always* put `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of every Perl script you write. Those two pragmas can save you a lot of painful debugging.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the default scope of foreach loop in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238576/what-is-the-default-scope-of-foreach-loop-in-perl)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the perldoc information regarding foreach loops: [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops)

> The foreach loop iterates over a normal list value and sets the
>   variable VAR to be each element of the list in turn. If the variable
>   is preceded with the keyword my, then it is lexically scoped, and is
>   therefore visible only within the loop. Otherwise, the variable is
>   implicitly local to the loop and regains its former value upon exiting
>   the loop. If the variable was previously declared with my, it uses
>   that variable instead of the global one, but it's still localized to
>   the loop. This implicit localization occurs only in a foreach loop.

If you want to retain the value of $i outside the loop then you can omit $i in the foreach loop call and use perl's special variable $_ an example below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $i = 0;
foreach (5..10){
    print $_."\n";
    $i = $_;
}
print "Outside loop i = $i\n";
```

5
6
7
8
9
10
Outside loop i = 10

Comment: What an explanation. Exactly what I was looking for. So does this means there isn't a way of preserving foreach loop variable value after loop exits?

Comment: If this is the case, then I will need to use another variable and assign it the loop variable value in each iteration. Isn't this is inefficient and extra work.

Comment: Even if you spell `foreach` as `for`, the localization occurs.  It looks like you'll need a spare variable to get the value of `$i` in the loop on each iteration.

Comment: @chammu it seems that you need a helper variable in regards to this, I will update my answer accordingly/

Comment: I got it. But this seems to be an extra work for no reason. Do you know if perl has any specific reason for going this way?

Comment: @chammu updated my answer found a way to use $_, perl's special variable, to save you a few lines

Comment: Changing from an explicitly named variable to `$_` is generally considered a step backwards for maintainability.  Usage of the "C style" `for` loop or a `while` loop is probably a better solution to this problem.

Comment: You can also do `foreach my $i (5..10)`

Answer (score 5):

`foreach` localize variable to the loop.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $adr;
my $i = 0;
foreach $i(5..10){
    $adr = \$i;
    print "$i ($adr)\n";
}
$adr = \$i;
print "Outside loop i = $i ($adr)\n";
```

output

```
5 (SCALAR(0x9d1e1d8))
6 (SCALAR(0x9d1e1d8))
7 (SCALAR(0x9d1e1d8))
8 (SCALAR(0x9d1e1d8))
9 (SCALAR(0x9d1e1d8))
10 (SCALAR(0x9d1e1d8))
Outside loop i = 0 (SCALAR(0x9d343a0))
```

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html),

> The foreach loop iterates over a normal list value and sets the variable VAR to be each element of the list in turn. If the variable is preceded with the keyword my, then it is lexically scoped, and is therefore visible only within the loop. **Otherwise, the variable is implicitly local to the loop and regains its former value upon exiting the loop.** If the variable was previously declared with my, it uses that variable instead of the global one, **but it's still localized to the loop**. This implicit localization occurs only in a foreach loop.

To preserve value of `$i` you can use `C` like `for` loop,

```
my $i = 0;
for ($i = 5; $i <= 10; $i++) { .. }
```

although it's less readable than perl `foreach`

Comment: Here, I am not using foreach my $i. It that case I can expect it to localize.

Comment: But if I don't  give the declaration at the top which is my $i = 0, it will complain regarding variable being not declared

Comment: Your is working example of what is mentioned in link provided by @PrgmError . Thanks.

Comment: C-style loops may be less readable, but IMO are clearer when you do want the value to persist.  easy to make off-by-one errors though :)

Comment: note that the *reason* it is localized to the loop is that it really is aliasing the variable to each element in the list being iterated over (or emulating that, in the case of `..`), not setting the existing variable to each value in turn.

Comment: @ysth actually $i leaves the for loop incremented by 1 (11 not 10). `:/`

Comment: unless you `last` out, yes.  I guess there really isn't a good way to do what they ask for (loop including 10 but show 10 as the final value).  I think that's more of a reflection of asking for something you wouldn't normally want to do than anything else, though.

Comment: @ysth yes, it doesn't look like something you usually want to do. (btw, not quite an idiom https://eval.in/277180)

Comment: Correct, and I wouldn't like to maintain such code. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$i` is redefined in foreach scope at

```
foreach $i(5..10){
```

So the variable outside foreach will not change.