# Passing the value of a global variable inside a subroutine

Tags: perl, subroutine

Below is the code snippet i have written, here the problem is $server variable cannot be passed inside the subroutines. How can i pass the value of a global variable inside a subroutine. Please help!

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my (@list,$server);

    @list = qw/server1.net server2.net server3.net/;

    foreach $server(@list) {
    #calling sub-routines
    command1(); 
    command2();
    }

    sub command1 {
    print $server;
    system("command1");
    }

    sub command2 {
    print $server;
    system("command2");
    }
```

Comment: why use globals instead of passing the variable as argument ?

Comment: [Crossposted to PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1218119).

Comment: The obvious answer is to pass the `$server` variable into the subroutines (`command1($server)`). But you say "the problem is $server variable cannot be passed inside the subroutines". It would be interesting to here what is preventing you from doing that.

Comment: (1) It is very unreasonable that a variable can't be local and passed to a subroutine.  You'd have to explain it really well why this is so  (2) Given that, with `foreach (@servers) { func() };` the `$_` in the loop (another server in each iteration) is seen in the sub `func` as `$_`, so the sub is then `sub func { $server = $_ ... }`.  But this is horrible and I hope you can just normally, explicitly and transparently, pass to the function what it needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most important rules of good programming is to reduce [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)). Reducing a piece of code's dependencies on other pieces of code increases readability, increases maintainability, and decrease the chance of errors.

Your subs should not rely on having a global variable declared and available. The subs should have a server parameter instead.

For the same reason, you should also be limiting the scope of your variables to where they are needed.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

sub command1 {
   my ($server) = @_;
   say $server;
   system("command1", $server);
}

sub command2 {
   my ($server) = @_;
   say $server;
   system("command2", $server);
}

{
   my @servers = qw( server1.net server2.net server3.net );

   for my $server (@servers) {
      command1($server); 
      command2($server);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

.. if you want to use globals:

```
our $server;
my (@list);

... rest of the code ...
```

or when you want to keep it a lexical, see also [Perl foreach loop variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28306510/perl-foreach-loop-variable-scope)

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my (@list, $server);

@list = qw/server1.net server2.net server3.net/;

foreach (@list) {
  $server = $_;   # <<-- use it this way
  #calling sub-routines
  command1();
  command2();
}

sub command1 {
  print $server;
  system("command1");
}

sub command2 {
  print $server;
  system("command2");
}
```

preferred: pass as argument like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my (@list);

@list = qw/server1.net server2.net server3.net/;

foreach my $server(@list) {
  #calling sub-routines
  command1($server);
  command2($server);
}

sub command1 {
  my ($server) = @_;
  print $server, "\n";
  system("command1");
}

sub command2 {
  my ($server) = @_;
  print $server, "\n";
  system("command2");
}
```

Comment: Why do you insist on using a package variable for a global? Lexicals make perfectly good global variables.

Comment: update because of @Borodin's question. Bottom line is keep away from using globals. A trap is easily created. Using `$server` as a lexical here in the foreach does not do what you think it would

Comment: @ikegami: `local `? : *Can't localize lexical variable $server*

Comment: Oh sorry,  I thought you were using `our`. You're actually *increasing* the scope by using `my` instead of `our`+`local`.